# Install BitNami Wordpress for Mac

Tags: wordpress, passwords, xampp, bitnami

I'm trying to install BitNami Wordpress on XAMPP for Mac, but I have a slight problem here. There's this Create Admin Account dialog box on my way through installation and it seems to require me to fill the boxes in. It's asking for Login, My real name, Email address, My existing MySQL password for Bitnami. I don't know what kind of password I should type in, since I haven't even typed in any password for anything. I've tried to enter the password I set up in for phpMyAdmin, but that doesn't work, I also tried to leave it blank and click Next, but it won't allow me, says: enter password.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami developer here.

You're trying to install bitnami wordpress **module** and it needs a wamp installation (that's why it asks you to input a password).

You should install bitnami wordpress **stack**, that already comes with the wamp (you'll be asked to set an admin account).